# Combining and Filtering Daily Data Sets in R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to find the most efficient way to use a large collection of daily transaction data sets. Here is an example of one day's data set:

```
Date                Time        Name          Price        Quantity 
2005/01/03          012200      Dave          1.40         1  
2005/01/03          012300      Anne          1.35         2  
2005/01/03          015500      Steve         1.54         1  
2005/01/03          021500      Dave          1.44         15  
2005/01/03          022100      James         1.70         7
```

In the real data, there are ~40,000 rows per day, and each day is a separate comma-delimited .txt file.  The data go from 2005 all the way to today. I am only interested in "Dave" and "Anne," (as well as 98 other names) but there are thousands of other people in the set.  Some days may have multiple entries for a given person, some days may have none for a given person. Since there is a large amount of data, what would be the most efficient way of extracting and combining all of the data for "Anne," "Dave," and the other 98 individuals (Ideally into 100 separate data sets)?

The two ways I would think off are:

1) filtering each day to only "Dave" or "Anne" and then appending to one big data set.

2) Appending all days to one big data set and the filtering to "Dave" or "Anne."

Which method would give me the most efficient results?  And is there a better method that I can't think of?

Thank you for the help!

Andy

Comment: Depending on the approach you use, I don't think you'll see much of a difference in either approach. Either way, you have to read in at most 4,380 files with an average of 40,000 rows, resulting in ~175.2 million rows of data. Both methods require reading those data, so that's a constant cost. The question becomes whether it's less expensive to filter 4,380 times on small data, or one time on large data. If you're using the `tidyverse`, the difference in time is probably negligible. Either way, this seems like something that can be easily tested on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question can be answered analytically.

#### Workflow

As @Frank had pointed it out, the method may depend on the processing requirements:

- Is this a one-time exercise?
  Then the feasibility of both methods can be further investigated.
- Is this a repetitive task where the actual daily transaction data should be added?
  Then method 2 might be less efficient if it processes the whole bunch of data anew at every repetition.

#### Memory requirement

R keeps all data in memory (unless one of the special "big memory" packages is used). So, one of the constraints is the available memory of the computer system used for this task.

As already pointed out in [brittenb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492418/combining-and-filtering-daily-data-sets-in-r#comment77946545_45492418) there are 12 years of daily data files summing up to a total of 12 * 365 = 4380 files. Each file contains about 40 k rows.

The 5 rows sample data set provided in the question can be used to create a 40 k rows dummy file by replication:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "Date                Time        Name          Price        Quantity 
  2005/01/03          012200      Dave          1.40         1  
  2005/01/03          012300      Anne          1.35         2  
  2005/01/03          015500      Steve         1.54         1  
  2005/01/03          021500      Dave          1.44         15  
  2005/01/03          022100      James         1.70         7  ",
  colClasses = c(Time = "character")
)
DT40k <- rbindlist(replicate(8000L, DT, simplify = FALSE))

str(DT40k)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    40000 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ Date    : chr  "2005/01/03" "2005/01/03" "2005/01/03" "2005/01/03" ...
>  $ Time    : chr  "012300" "012300" "012300" "012300" ...
>  $ Name    : chr  "Anne" "Anne" "Anne" "Anne" ...
>  $ Price   : num  1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 1.35 ...
>  $ Quantity: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "Name"
> ```

```
print(object.size(DT40k), units = "Mb")
```

> ```
> 1.4 Mb
> ```

For method 2, at least 5.9 Gb (4380 * 1.4 Mb) of memory is required to hold all rows (unfiltered) in one object.

If your computer system is limited in memory then method 1 might be the way to go. The OP has mentioned that he is only interested to keep the transaction data of just 100 names out of several thousand. So after filtering, the data volume finally might be reduced to 1% to 10% of the original volume, i.e., to 60 Mb to 600 Mb.

#### Speed

Disk I/O is usually the performance bottleneck. With the fast I/O functions included in the `data.table` package we can simulate the time needed for reading all 4380 files.

```
# write file with 40 k rows
fwrite(DT40k, "DT40k.csv")

# measure time to read the file
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fread = tmp <- fread("DT40k.csv", colClasses = c(Time = "character"))
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq    max neval
>  fread 34.73596 35.43184 36.90111 36.05523 37.14814 52.167   100
> ```

So, reading all 4380 files should take less than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, and if storage space is not an issue, you should go with option 2.  This gives you a lot more flexibility in the long run (say you want to add / remove names in the future).

Always easier to trim the data rather than regret not collecting it.  The only reason I would go with option 1 is is storage or speed is a bottleneck in your workflow.